# Using OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler with Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-security

I'm in the proccess of upgrading from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3.

I had this working class with Spring Security 5:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

        @Value("${domain}")
        private String shortDomain;

        @Value("${vps}")
        private String shortVps;

        private List<String> origins() {
                return List.of("http://" + shortVps, "http://localhost:3000",
                                "http://localhost:8080", "http://" + shortVps + ":8080",
                                "https://" + shortDomain, "https://www." + shortDomain,
                                "http://" + shortDomain, "http://www." + shortDomain).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Bean
        TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
                return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(origins());
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(
                                List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

                http
                                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                                                .mvcMatchers("/toto",
                                                                "/titi",
                                                                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                                                "/sitemap.xml")
                                                .permitAll()
                                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                                .oauth2Login()
                                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                return http
                                .csrf().disable()
                                .cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration)
                                .and()
                                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(),
                                                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                                .build();
        }

}
```

I had a custom OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean.

As far as I understand, upgrading to Spring Security 6, I should do this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

        @Value("${domain}")
        private String shortDomain;

        @Value("${vps}")
        private String shortVps;

        private List<String> origins() {
                return List.of("http://" + shortVps, "http://localhost:3000",
                                "http://localhost:8080", "http://" + shortVps + ":8080",
                                "https://" + shortDomain, "https://www." + shortDomain,
                                "http://" + shortDomain, "http://www." + shortDomain).stream().distinct()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Bean
        TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
                return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
                CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(origins());
                corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(
                                List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
                corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
                source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
                return source;
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http
                                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                                                .requestMatchers("/toto",
                                                                "/titi",
                                                                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                                                "/sitemap.xml")
                                                .permitAll()
                                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
                                //HELP! .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                return http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(),
                                                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                                .build();
        }

}
```

My question is: how can I deal with the OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler with these new methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) and newest [Lambda DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html)

Instead of

```
                        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
                        //HELP! .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
```

Do it:

```
   http.oauth2Login(oAuthLogin -> oAuthLogin.successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler));
   http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
```